# which is grammatically correct? it can help your company improve or improves

Tags: verbs

Which s grammatically correct? it can help your company improve or improves?

Comment: There is an implicit “to” before your verb.  Hence, it has to be in infinitive form.

Answer (score 2):

After the verb "help", you should use an infinitive. The infinitive form can be either a "to infinitive" or a "bare infinitive", so you should say:

> It can help your company **improve / to improve** (I think the bare infinitive form is preferred in American English).

So it's not correct to use "improves" in your sentence.